# How to create swagger array

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to create a swagger doc for below JSON, but I'm getting the below error: **schemas with 'type: array', require a sibling 'items: ' field**

JSON:

```
{
    "_id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "descriptions": {},
    "date": "string",
    "customer": {
        "id": "string",
        "name": {
            "firstName": "string",
            "lastName": "string",
            "middleName": "string"
        }
    },
    "productDetials": {
        "id": "string",
        "name": {
            "name": "string",
            "model": "string",
            "price": "string",
            "comments": "string"
        }
    },
    "Phone": [{
            "id": "string",
            "category": "string",
            "version": "string",
            "condition": "string",
            "availability": "string"

        }
    ]   
}
```

Can someone help me to get the swagger doc for this JSON.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you have to define models dependent on the JSON (objects).

In your case:

- `Order` (I guess)
- `Customer`
- `CustomerName`
- `ProductDetails`
- `ProductName`
- `Phone`

Then define the models in `definitions` section of the YAML (Swagger schema documentation):

```
Order:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    _id:
      type: "string"
    name:
      type: "string"
    descriptions:
      type: "object"
    date:
      type: "string"
    customer:
      $ref: "#/definitions/Customer"
    productDetails:
      $ref: "#/definitions/ProductDetails"
    phoneNumbers:
      type: "array"
      items:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Phone"
Customer:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    id:
      type: "string"
    name:
      $ref: "#/definitions/CustomerName"
CustomerName:       
  type: "object"
  properties:
    firstName:
      type: "string"
    lastName:
      type: "string"
    middleName:
      type: "string"
ProductDetails:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    id:
      type: "string"
    name:
      $ref: "#/definitions/ProductName"
ProductName:       
  type: "object"
  properties:
    name:
      type: "string"
    model:
      type: "string"
    price:
      type: "string"
    comments:
      type: "string"
Phone:
  type: "object"
  properties:
    id: 
      type: "string"
    category:
      type: "string"
    version:
      type: "string"
    condition:
      type: "string"
    availability:
      type: "string"
```

If you want to define an **array** with a specific model as item - take `array` as a `type` and define `items` (according to provided error code you forgot it). `items` is the content of the array - so the the `Phone` model in your case:

```
...
phoneNumbers:
  type: "array"
  items:
    $ref: "#/definitions/Phone"
```